# MySQL Workbench hangs/crashes while connecting to database

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I migrated to **Windows 10 from Windows 7 few days ago.** After installing mysql workbench I have tried to connect to local mysql server and AWS RDS server too. Every time I click "Test Connection" button it crashes. After few googling I saw this bug is reported here: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69572

But solution is not clear from above thread or I didn't get it. If anybody knows solution please let me know. I am tired to find solution of this bug.

- OS: Windows 10
- Mysql Workbench version: 6.3.6 CE

Comment: Try again with the upcoming version 8 of MySQL Workbench. We switched the SSH backend there.

Answer (score 8):

Strangely, after an upgrade, MySql Workbench crashed each time it connected to Server. As a quick fix, I deleted the connection and added a new one. Unexplainable, but it worked.

> Database > Manage Connections > Delete (similarly create new connection)

After I faced some serious issues combining MySql Workbench with MariaDB, I've switched over to [TeamSQL](https://teamsql.io). It is free and works well straight out of the box. However, it comes with a cost of two drawbacks:

1. It is slightly slower than Mysql Workbench
2. It has an aggressive way of reminding you for an update (which disturbed me the most)

[image: Permanant banner floating at the bottom]

Comment: it looks like TeamSQL is not around anymore.

Comment: I can confirm that teamsql has been closed. It was rebranded into a different but similar application that was a paid license called DataRow, which has also been discontinued. 

DBeaver is listed as another alternative. It is a free product that is still active, link to the github page below.
https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. In your operating system go to the services app
Step 2. In the service app look for mySQL80
Step 3. Start the service if it has been stopped
Step 4. Now test the connection to see if it works